# How to avoid scientific notation of a large double while converting to xml with xstream in Java

Tags: java, xml, xstream, scientific-notation

I'm using `xstream` to convert a object in xml format while the class has a double field.

Recently I found a object with a large double like `140936219.00`

But in the output xml file, it became:

```
<Person>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <amount>1.40936219E8</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <currencyAmount>1.40936219E8</currencyAmount>
</Person>
```

The codes in Java like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("Person", PersonBean.class);
return xstream.toXML(person);
```

May I ask how to avoid the scientific notation in this case? Basically what I want is :

```
<Person>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <amount>140936219.00</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <currencyAmount>140936219.00</currencyAmount>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own converter. For example

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DoubleConverter;

public class MyDoubleConverter extends DoubleConverter
{
    @Override
    public String toString(Object obj)
    {
        return (obj == null ? null : YourFormatter.format(obj));
    }
}
```

and then register it in a XStream object with high priority

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("Person", PersonBean.class);
xstream.registerConverter(new MyDoubleConverter(), XStream.PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH);
return xstream.toXML(person);
```

Comment: It's the solution. BTW `xstream` call `toString(Object obj)` method to convert object to xml?

Comment: Yes. All SingleValueConverters have to override toString to represent single value object. For more complex objects you can look at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter (these kinds of converters might be registered with the same way).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DecimalFormat class such as:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
...
double yourBigNumber = 140936219.00;
DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); //if you want to make it so it keeps the .00s
//then change the "#.#" to a "#.00".
String newNumber = formater.format(yourBigNumber);
System.out.println(newNumber); //Not needed ( if you couldn't tell :) )
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your String value of the big number, note the String is not in scientific notation.

Comment: I understand that it's a general way. But in may case, I need to pass `person` object to `xstream` for xml convertion and the `person` object hold a field with double type. When formatted, it becomes `String`